# Display another page's content without changing url

Tags: 7

I want to return different content for the front page according to some conditions. Actually there is already a function used as page callback; I want to simply return the modified content (a node with /other as path alias) from it.

Is there a way to display another page's content without changing the original called URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would do something like this in your page callback function:

```
// Resolve the alias "other" to get the normal path (node/%node)
$normal_path = drupal_get_normal_path('other');

menu_set_active_item($normal_path);
return menu_execute_active_handler(NULL, FALSE);
```